# Reposition class element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an eye icon and when you click on it the icon changes and it repositions via js: `left: 10%;`.

However, if there is an element in the DOM with the ID `login-section`, it should be repositioned to `left: 50%;`.

I tried `document.getElementsByClassName('fa-eye-slash').style.left = '50%';` but that doesn't work.

```js
let eye = document.querySelectorAll('.eye');
eye.forEach(function (v) {
    v.addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
    

        if(document.getElementById('login-section')) {
            // Following line is not working:
            document.getElementsByClassName('fa-eye-slash').style.left = '50%';
        }
       

    })
});
```

```css
.eye {
    position: absolute;
}
.fa-eye-slash {
    left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">

<div id='login-section'>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-eye eye"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). Do you maybe mean `document.getElementsByClassName('fa-eye-slash')[0].style.left = '50%'` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should select the element itself that was clicked and has the class `.fa-eye-slash`. Right now, it looks like you are trying to set the left property of all elements with the class `.fa-eye-slash`.

Additionally, you can use the style property to set the CSS style. But, since you want to toggle between two positions, it might be better to add and remove a CSS class that defines the left property.

Here's an example that might be helpful:

```
let eye = document.querySelectorAll('.eye');

eye.forEach(function (v) {
    v.addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');

        if (document.getElementById('login-section')) {
            if (this.classList.contains('fa-eye-slash')) {
                this.style.left = '50%'; 
            } else {
                this.style.left = '10%'; 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Jake Zappin it's working. Why might it be better to add and remove a CSS class? To make the website overall faster?

Comment: Generally, it is preferred in order to promote separation of concerns, reusability and improve performance by allowing batch processing of style changes.